# Using a screen capture program (ffmpeg with uscreencapture in my case) to record a Flash video playing on screen

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to capture my desktop, precisely a full screen video - think "YouTube video on full screen situation", or if you'd record a programme on iPlayer (or any other content deliverer) - what would you do? Everything's great - got video and audio of the 'full screen video', but the output video is somewhat wobbly/laggy.. it's not right, what I'm trying to say - people don't move smoothly. I think it might have to do with FPS?
Here's the command I'm using:
`ffmpeg -f dshow -i audio="Stereo Mix (Realtek High Defini":video="UScreenCapture" -r  24000/1001 -q 1 out.avi`

Any other programs that'd help me record a full screen playing video cleanly, that'd also help :)

Cheers!

Comment: Does it look better if you remove `-r 24000/1001`? I'm not sure what the default input frame rate is since the [dshow documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#dshow) does not specify (and I did not investigate further). If you do not specify an input frame rate, then the default is used, and if you specify a different value for the output, then that will case frame dropping or frame duplication which may cause the laggy look. Also try a faster encoder: `ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast output.mp4`

Comment: Removing the `-r 24000/1001` and using a faster encoder didn't help. Would it help if I'd send you a clip of the output, so that you'd understand what I mean by 'wobbly/laggy' look? Or you imagine it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a performance issue. Tried to record a full screen video (720p) playing on my screen, on an i7 CPU laptop, and I can't see the output video having this wobbly/laggy look.
Then again, on my desktop computer, when I just play the video on browser, I don't get any lag too. So it becomes laggy during the recording process, and in the output file. So yeah, problem solved.